# Post several strongly typed model via Ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to send my controller several models represented in my view by several _PartialView.
Ex : My main page contains the field of the object Model but it contains also a Partial View that contains the field of the object ModelDetail.

I'd like the action in the controller to be like :

```
public ActionResult SaveAll(Model model, ModelDetail detail)
{
    ........
}
```

So i made a function like that :

```
var MainInfo = $('form#MainInfo').serialize();
var DetailInfo = $('#Details :input').serialize();
var dataPost = { model: MainInfo , modelDetail: DetailInfo };
 $.post(saveCompleteUrl, dataPost).sucess() {
 }
 ...........
```

But it is not working, both parameters are null in the Controller. And I can't initialize the objects because in Details i have a collection that contains n object...

Is there anyway to make this work or do I need to have to seperate Action ? One to save the Main Model the Second to save the Details. I know this solution works but I'd rather use the other one.

EDIT : 2015/06/29 :
I tryed plenty of different ways to do it but I never succeeded, the data inside the object are always null, the only way I can get it to work is like that :

```
 var litigationMainInfo = $('form#MainLitigationInfo').serialize();
            var litigationDetailInfo = $('#litigationDetails :input').serialize();
            $.post(saveUrl, litigationMainInfo)
                .success(function (data) {
                    var actionResult = data.Result;
                    if (actionResult.Success) {
                        $.post(saveDetailsUrl, litigationDetailInfo)
                              .success ....
```

with

```
SaveUrl = '@Url.Action("Save", "Litigation")',"Save"
saveDetailsUrl = '@Url.Action("SaveDetails", "Litigation")',"Save"
```

and

```
[AjaxOnly]
public ActionResult Save(EditModel model){...}

[AjaxOnly]
public ActionResult SaveDetails(DetailEditModel model){...}
```

BUT this :

```
public ActionResult Save(EditViewModel m){...}

public class EditViewModel
{
     EditModel model;
     DetailEditModel detailModel;
}

var MainInfo = $('form#MainInfo').serialize();
var DetailInfo = $('#Details :input').serialize();
var dataPost = { model: MainInfo , detailModel: DetailInfo };
 $.post(saveCompleteUrl, dataPost).sucess() {
 }
```

The methods signature I used were :

```
public ActionResult SaveComplete(ViewModel model){...}
public ActionResult SaveComplete(EditModel editModel, EditDetailModel detailsModel){...}
```

Strangely here, EditModel is null but DetailEditModel is not. The values in DetailEditModel are set to Default values though (0 for Ids, null for string)

I don't understand when I do it in two call this is "working" but as soon as I want to send the two models in the same call it does not work.

By the way, the cshtml main page is composed by 2 PartialViews The first is binded to EditModel. The second is also binded to EditModel because I use the id of the object to get the details but the second partial view is a tab Strip  (KendoUI) defined like this :

@model FileEditModel

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("tabStrip")
    .Items(tabStrip => {
        tabStrip.Add().Text("Details")
            .Selected(true)
            .LoadContentFrom("GetDetails", "Litigation", new { LitigationFileId = Model.Id });
```

This is the GetDetails method :

```
public ActionResult GetDetails(int Id)
        {
            if (LitigationFileId != 0)
            {
                DetailEditModel model = LoadData(Id);
                return PartialView("_details", model);
            }
            else
            {
                DetailEditModel model = new DetailEditModel();
                return PartialView("_details", model);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the example you posted would work fine if you changed the  3rd line to this: var dataPost = { model: MainInfo , detail: DetailInfo };

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a view model class containing a property for each class

```
public class ViewModel 
{
     public Model Model;
     public ModelDetail ModelDetail;
}

public ActionResult SaveAll(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    ........
}
```

Your ajax call should work perfect with this server side change

Comment: So I tried this solution and indeed the object is not null anymore but the properties are not set. The code I Used : var MainInfo = $('form#MainInfo').serialize();
var DetailInfo = $('#Details :input').serialize();
var dataPost = { model: MainInfo , modelDetail: DetailInfo };
 $.post(saveCompleteUrl, dataPost).sucess() {
 } Is there any way to recreate the ViewModel from the object that compose it ? I also changed the model user in my View to be binded to the new ViewModel

Comment: @Guigui: check before submit that properties names from `MainInfo` and `DetailInfo` match server side class properties, otherwise it will never be filled